# Proof that left and right derivatives are equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to prove that

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{f(t+\epsilon)-f(t)}{\epsilon}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{f(t)-f(t-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$$

for all differentiable $f:T\to X$ but I don't know how to do it.

Intuitively it seems this must be true, because if we zoom in far enough at a point it can be aproximated by a linear function, meaning the left and right derivatives must be equal. The problem is I don't know how to prove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about substituting $t=u-\varepsilon$ then replace $u=t$